# String to zip file

Tags: c#, io

I use a webservice that returns a zip file, as a string, and not bytes as I expected. I tried to write it to the disk, but when I open it, it tells me that it is corrupt. What am I doing wrong?

```
string cCsv = oResponse.fileCSV;//this is the result from webservice
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cCsv));
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("test.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    ms.WriteTo(file);
}
ms.Close();
```

Comment: Could you add the bit of code where you ask your webservice for this csv file ?

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without knowing how the `cCsv` string is supposed to be interpreted.  It doesn't sound like you know either.  Do you have any more formal information/specification regarding what the web service returns?

Comment: You can't pass raw binary data via web service, so your response is somehow text-encoded (for example BASE64). You have to decode the text data back to binary first.

Comment: If the zip file is coming back as a string then it's probably encoded in some textual format. You'll need to decode it (to get the bytes back) and then write it to the file.

Comment: maybe try printing or writing the string, or just using a stop point on it to see what it looks like and what characters it's using. That'll give you an idea for its type of encoding. I would think [UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx) and then [UTF-16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) would be good first and second guesses.

Comment: This is the string (truncate for post limit) that I receive from the service:
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

Comment: Did you try the code I posted below trying these three encodings: UTF-8, UTF-16, and ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solve the problem:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("testbase64.zip", Convert.FromBase64String(cCsv));
```

Comment: This looks good using Base64 and directly writing bytes using `WriteAllBytes`... you should accept this as answer.

Comment: I tried to accept as answer but I get a message about something over 21 hours.....

Comment: O yea, because you're [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) you need to wait 48 hours from posting before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of encoding the string is in, but assuming [UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx), the following should work. [UTF-16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) would be another guess.

```
string cCsv = oResponse.fileCSV;
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create("test.zip")))
{
    bw.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cCsv));
}
```

It'd be informative to look at the characters and the raw string itself being returned.

**Edit**

Per Frank's answer, the correct encoding is [base64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx), which of course makes sense because it's binary data stored as a string.

Also, per Frank's answer, if the only action is to directly write a single byte array, then `File.WriteAllBytes` is more compact.

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything, UTF 16 does not exist, I used UTF32,but the error I receive is always opening the file: unknown format

Comment: Ok, looks like you solved it with Base64, and simplified the code by directly writing the byte array. Base64 makes perfect sense given that it's binary data stored as a string, derp, I should have recommended that first :(   FYI, UTF-16 does exist, but .Net is confusing because it calls UTF-16 "Unicode", which is entirely misleading because UTF-32 is Unicode also, but UTF-16 is .Net's default. Just something to be aware of.